# How call a method every hour in API REST C# in IIS

Tags: c#

I need excute a method every hour in my project API REST  publish in IIS, I tried that:

In method Application_Start in class WebApiApplication,I put this

```
 timerBack = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = time,
            Enabled = true,
            AutoReset = true
        };
        timerBack.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(testmethod);
```

But never call Application_Start,

please help me.

Comment: Unless I've been using it wrong all these years, IIS isn't a good scheduled task system. It's for hosting web applications, that are by nature stateless. If you need to run a task on a regular basis, a console app fired off by Scheduler or a service may be a better fit for you. It can still call an action in your WebAPI that does the work, but the scheduling shouldn't be part of the WebApp.

Comment: I agree with @gilliduck. Also the approach i usually use is doing action in a method that is been called in short duration by user.

Comment: Agree with above.  You might want to consider _Windows Task Scheduler_

Comment: I suppose another alternative would be to use something like [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), but I favor the approach that @gilliduck provided.

Comment: Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish, OP? Application_Start doesn't execute until the process is activated, usually with the first inbound HTTP request, unless you set it up to [warm up](https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2010/05/06/keep-your-aspnet-websites-warm-and-fast-247).

Answer (score 4):

IIS isn't a good scheduled task system. It's for hosting web applications, that are by nature stateless. If you need to run a task on a regular basis, a console app fired off by Scheduler or a service may be a better fit for you. It can still call an action in your WebAPI that does the work, but the scheduling shouldn't be part of the WebApp.

In addition I should mention that keeping alive a session in IIS is brittle and fraut with problems. By default it will kill a session in 20 minutes of no activity (which is typically measured by requests to the server). Even by adding something to application start, your wanting it to do something long after it's been killed.

Long story short, what you want to do can't (shouldn't) be done without engaging in brittle, kludgy, hacks. It's just not what it's designed to do.